# Quicksort algorithm implementation

Tags: python

This is an extract from a working quicksort implementation. However, it uses the first item as the pivot and I need it to be able to swap between using the first and last item. How would I go about doing this? (Changing pivot_pointer = list[start] to pivot_pointer = list[end] outputs unsorted data.)

Thanks

```
def recursive_split(list, start, end):
   if start < end:
       split = qsortpartition(list, start, end)
       recursive_split(list, start, split - 1)
       recursive_split(list, split + 1, end)


def qsortpartition(list, start, end):
    left_pointer = start + 1
    right_pointer = end
    pivot_pointer = list[start]

    while not pointers_converged:
        while left_pointer <= right_pointer and \
            list[left_pointer] >= pivot_pointer:

            left_pointer += 1

        while list[right_pointer] <= pivot_pointer and \
            right_pointer >= left_pointer:

            right_pointer -= 1

        if right_pointer < left_pointer:
            pointers_converged = True

        else:
            list = switch(list, left_pointer, right_pointer)

    list = switch(list, start, right_pointer)

    return right_pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting implementation

I made a few changes to it I'll show below:

In helper function:

```
   helper(alist, start, split - 1)
   helper(alist, split + 1, end)
```

to:

```
   helper(alist, start, split - 1)
   helper(alist, split + 1, end)
```

It's due to return of partition will change too:

In partition function:

```
left = start + 1
right = end
pivot = alist[start]
```

to:

```
left = start
right = end - 1
pivot = alist[end]
```

and

```
    alist = switch(alist, start, right)
return right
```

to:

```
alist = switch(alist, left, end)
return left
```

Full mod code:

```
def qsort(alist):
    helper(alist, 0, len(counts) - 1)

def helper(alist, start, end):
   if start < end:
       split = partition(alist, start, end)
       helper(alist, start, split - 1)
       helper(alist, split + 1, end)

def partition(alist, start, end):
    left = start
    right = end - 1
    pivot = alist[end]

    while True:
        while left <= right and \
            alist[left] >= pivot:
            left += 1
        while alist[right] <= pivot and \
            right >= left:
            right -= 1
        if right < left:
            break
        else:
            alist = switch(alist, left, right)
    alist = switch(alist, left, end)
    return left

def switch(alist, x, y):
    temp = alist[x]
    alist[x] = alist[y]
    alist[y] = temp
    return alist
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the last item as the pivot element just swap the first element with the last element and 
 continue as usual:

```
def partition(alist, start, end):
    left = start + 1
    right = end
    switch(alist,start,end)
    pivot = alist[start]
```